# Upgrading a live 8.04 LTS server to more up-to-date version

Tags: server, upgrade, php, 8.04, moodle

Running Apache, MySQL, PHP with Moodle 1.9.9 running as a school based CMS.
All possible updates for 8.04 have been applied.

Moodle 2.x from Versions 2.1 onwards needs Php version 5.3.2 which is included in more recent distribution version.

Would I be better (safer) upgrading php & mysql or upgrading Ubuntu to a more recent version?
- if upgrading Ubuntu is better, are there any caveats I should know before attempting this?

I will be taking a copy of the entire server before doing any upgrading.
Hoping to run on a test version also.

Bit green on Linux hence lack of confidence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading Ubuntu to a later release is a better option, as 8.04 Server will be end of life next April. Upgrading to 12.04 will mean there will be security updates until April 2017, at least.

Caveats with upgrading, either Ubuntu release, or just individual pieces of software, are the same. As software is developed and improved, it may have changes to configuration files, or file system layout, which may conflict with what you are currently using; requiring you to deal with differences. Also, libraries may also at some point break ABI and/or API, causing any applications you've developed on top of them, to no longer work correctly. But again, these are all things you'll have to deal with, regardless of how you upgrade the software.

Comment: OK, I think I should get some help to do this then.
I can sort some things, but just dont have the experience with it to risk an upgrade on the live production server. Thanks.